# Evaluation of gene regulatory network

Tags: mutual-information, networks

I am new to this forum and data science, I will try my best to describe my question.

Question background:
I am molecular biology student and have recently inferred a gene expression network using 105 RNASeq gene expression datasets related to a bacterium, CLR algorithm from Minet R package. This network has 1784 nodes and 9897 edges. Now I would like to evaluate the network and determine precision recall metrics. Minet package has validate function where one compares their network with a reference network.

My question or problem:
I do not have a reference network to compare my network to in order to evaluate my network. Could you please let me know if there is a straight forward software or R package to generate a synthetic network and to validate my network or if there are synthetic bacterial networks with at least 1784 nodes that I could use for this purpose.

Finally, thank you very much and please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Best,
Ash

PS: I am an amateur when it comes to using R or data science. Learning snew mething e

Comment: Welcome on Cross Validated. I don't think this site is the right place to ask about R packages (off-topic) or the generation or use of a synthetic network for RNA-Seq experiments (Bioinformatics beta would be a better fit, IMO).

Comment: @chl this question, although posed from a bioinformatics/software perspective, gets to the problem of trying to apply criteria from supervised learning to a situation in which learning is unsupervised. I answered from that perspective.

Comment: @EdM Fair point (+1).

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, I don't think that you can do what you wish to validate your results.

Things like precision/recall metrics* apply when you have known classifications and you are trying to see how well a model succeeds at assigning cases to classes. Classifications in this situation are whether or not 2 nodes (genes) share an edge (connection) in the network. Each potential edge is assigned to a "doesn't exist" or an "exists" class.

In the software package you cite, that evaluation shows how well the reconstruction of a network from gene-expression data captures a particular known network of gene associations. In that case, for each potential edge (connection) between two nodes (genes), you know whether or not there "really" is an edge. Precision and recall represent how well the edges predicted by the algorithm agree with what is known to be the case. Agreement provides reassurance that the method (using mutual information between gene-expression values to infer connections) fundamentally works.

As I understand your situation, however, your building of a network is based solely on the information you provide via the gene-expression data. There is no ground truth about which genes (nodes) are connected via edges. What you have is thus a type of [unsupervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsupervised_learning), in which you learn associations directly from the data. So unless you have independent knowledge of the actual structure of the underlying network, there is no ground truth against which to test your model. Whether or not your network corresponds with some similarly sized (real or synthetic) network of bacterial genes wouldn't contain information about how well *your* network represents the true relationships within *your* bacterium--unless that's the already known network for your bacterium.

There might be some interesting ways to look at similarities/differences between your networks and those of related bacterial species, see how well different gene-expression data sets agree with respect to the inferred networks, estimate the sensitivity of your network to vagaries in the underlying data, and so on. But those aren't directly connected to precision and recall.

---

*You will find many pages on this site that question the general usefulness of precision/recall, accuracy, and F-scores of the type that the package in question reports. The important point here is the distinction between supervised and unsupervised learning, explained for example in [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/), Section 2.1.4 and in Chapter 10.